# CreateJS: Elements in Stage or Canvas are not scaling properly on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

So I am adjusting the size of the stage (canvas) upon window resize. While the canvas itself is readjusting correctly, the content of the canvas are not really scaling and in some cases some of the elements (ex: text, buttons etc.) aren't fully visible.

Here's the code

```
stage = new Stage(document.getElementById("canvas"));

window.addEventListener('resize',resize,false);

function resize() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  var ow = stage.canvas.width;
  var oh = stage.canvas.height;

  // keep aspect ratio
  scale = Math.min(w / ow, h / oh);
  stage.scaleX = scale;
  stage.scaleY = scale;

  // adjust canvas size
  stage.width = ow * scale;
  stage.height = oh * scale;

  stage.update();
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

A few quick things:

You can't set the width/height of the stage, but should instead set the size of the canvas. You also don't *need* to constrain its aspect ratio, unless you are trying to crop content.

```
stage.width = ow * scale;
stage.height = oh * scale;
```

Next, you might consider putting your content in a Container, and scaling that, instead of the stage directly.

Hope that helps!